# Unable to run a subprocess with code, the commond works on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, libreoffice, headless

I am generating a `PDF` from `.docx` file using `LibreOffice`. This is my sub-process command:

```
output = subprocess.call('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export' + out_folder + ' ' + input_docx + ' -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}',shell=True)
```

When I run this on terminal `PDF` is generating properly but when I call this sub-process. It gives `127 error code`.

Comment: it probably doesnt know where libreoffice is, give it the full path

Comment: @Nullman I have tried with full libreoffice path. I think the {USER} can be the issue since it needs root user privilages and in my code user is empty.

Comment: why not substitute the user yourself before calling? you can get the current USER from `os.environ['USER']`

Comment: I have given root user as you suggested but still, I am having this error. Do you have any idea or packages? I have already tried preview-generator. All of my code working in local properly but not on my server as well as on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code you can get your expected result.

```
import subprocess

out_folder = '/var/www/html/SocketQueue'
input_docx='/home/dhamo/Downloads/CNGroup_estimates.docx'
subprocess.call(['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to','pdf:writer_pdf_Export', '--outdir', out_folder, input_docx,
'-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}'])
```

Comment: Try to add full path to your libreoffice in your subprocess.

Comment: This is the error I am having but my libreoffice path is "/usr/sbin/libreoffice" but it says not found for my path 
'/usr/sbin/libreoffice: 46: /usr/sbin/libreoffice: dirname: not found\n/usr/sbin/libreoffice

Comment: which environment u running ?? whether its local environment or remote ??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. I have setup code on local machine and also one of my servers. In my local machine it's working. On my server, I have 2 apps which have pdf generation code one of them is working and another one is not.

Comment: My problem is fixed now. I have removed path from my gunicorn service. :)