# in a net core webapp,use libreoffice ,error:libreoffice: dirname: not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, libreoffice

I am generating a PDF from .docx file using LibreOffice. in ubuntu,This is my code:(.net core)

```
var sf = $"-headless -writer --convert-to pdf   /home/parasaga/resource/testtxt.txt --outdir /home/parasaga/resource";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "/usr/bin/libreoffice",
            Arguments = sf,
            UseShellExecute = false, 
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = startInfo,

        };
```

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

When I run this on terminal PDF is generating properly,consoleApp is ok too, but when I call this in a webapp, It gives error code:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 46: /usr/bin/libreoffice: dirname: not found,
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 48: /usr/bin/libreoffice: basename: not found
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 49: /usr/bin/libreoffice: sed: not found
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 49: /usr/bin/libreoffice: ls: not found
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 51: /usr/bin/libreoffice: dirname: not found
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 137: /usr/bin/libreoffice: grep: not found
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: i have no idea,but i find a similar question:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139542/unable-to-run-a-subprocess-with-code-the-commond-works-on-terminal)

Comment: maybe the problem is this :  the webapp install as a Daemons